# Android Studio + OpenCV - Realtime changing value in "onCameraFrame" function

Tags: java, android, opencv, oncreate

I have problem with my code. I want change return value in real time. I am working on app (openCV + Java). Is it possible to change return value in "Mat onCameraFrame()" function when application is working ?

Here is a code

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    getWindow().addFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_KEEP_SCREEN_ON);

    mOpenCvCameraView = (CameraBridgeViewBase)findViewById(R.id.camera_view);
    mOpenCvCameraView.setVisibility(SurfaceView.VISIBLE);
    mOpenCvCameraView.setCvCameraViewListener(this);

    button_rgb = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button_rgb);
    button_gray = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button_grey);
    show_text = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.show_text);

    show_text.setText("GRAY");
    gray_active = true;

    button_rgb.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            show_text.setText("RGB");
            rgb_active = true;
        }
    });

@Override
public Mat onCameraFrame(CameraBridgeViewBase.CvCameraViewFrame inputFrame) {

    mRgba = inputFrame.rgba();

    if (gray_active == true) {
        Imgproc.cvtColor(mRgba, imgGray, Imgproc.COLOR_RGB2GRAY);
        return imgGray;
    }

    else if (edge_active == true){
        Imgproc.cvtColor(imgGray, imgCanny, 50, 150);
        return imgCanny;
    }

    else {
        return mRgba;
    }
}
```

Comment: What exact problems are you experiencing?

Comment: Is it possible to change return value in onCameraFrame and it is all in realtime ? For example, with some button I can change rgb image to gray ?

Comment: Sure, it is intended to do that (See [JavaDoc](http://docs.opencv.org/java/3.1.0/org/opencv/android/CameraBridgeViewBase.CvCameraViewListener2.html#onCameraFrame-org.opencv.android.CameraBridgeViewBase.CvCameraViewFrame-)). Read "[How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)" and complete your question please.